# Python Error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I'm trying to make code and save the csv file named as
filename = "title" + "today's date and time" + ".csv"

```
from datetime import date
import csv

filename = "title_" + str(date.today()) + ".csv"
f = open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline="")
writer = csv.writer(f)
```

this seem to be working and file is saved as "title_2020-12-03.csv"

But I want to make file name with the time as well
so I tried

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
today = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M")

filename = "title_" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M") + ".csv"
f = open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline="")
writer = csv.writer(f)
```

but this gives me an error

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'title_2020/12/03_11:22.csv'

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dashes instead of slashes in the date it works:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
today = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M")

filename = "title_" + str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M")) + ".csv"
f = open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline="")
writer = csv.writer(f)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i still receive the same error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'title_2020-12-03_08:51.csv'

Comment: `:` also isn't allowed in a file name, at least on Windows.

Comment: @MrFuppes: Thank you, that may be the reason, myself I am using Linux and no problems. Perhaps @Zack Lee try with a period or `h`, like `filename = "title_" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%M") + ".csv"`

Comment: @MrFuppes Thank you after removing ":" it works

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that the required filename will be recognized as a modified filepath to your file because of the slashes (`'/'`).

So in case of the name `'title_2020/12/03_11:22.csv'` you won't find a file with the same name in the directory relative to the cwd of the execution, but rather the program will interpret the filename as a path and will try to look up the file `'03_11:22.csv'` in the `'title_2020/12/'` directory.

Therefore you should use a different delimiter that doesn't confront with filepaths on your system. In general the safest is to use dashes or underscores.

Comment: Thank you for your help, after removing '/' and ':' it's working